# Type 'Any' has no subscript members - while removing duplicate entries

Tags: arrays, swift, set, nsdictionary

I want to remove duplicate dictionaries from my nsarray on basis of one of key which my dictionaries contains

But I'm getting this error:

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

I am getting error on below line

```
guard let name = $0["profile_id"] as? String else {return nil }
```

here is my code...

```
var set = Set<String>()
let arraySet: [[String : Any]] = arry.compactMap {
    guard let name = $0["profile_id"] as? String else {return nil }
    return set.insert(name).inserted ? $0 : nil
}
```

Can any help me out ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the type of `arry`? It seems like the compiler thinks its `[Any]`.

Comment: This is Swift. Do not use NSArray.

Comment: @DávidPásztor : arry contains dictionaries

Comment: show your response of `arry` and also show the proper code from whom your are fetching ` profile_id`

Comment: arry contains dictionaries - you should explicitly cast it as **Any** is passive

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var set = Set<String>()
let arraySet: [[String : Any]] = arry.compactMap {
   guard let dic = $0 as? [String:Any], let name = dic["profile_id"] else {return nil }
   return set.insert(name).inserted ? dic : nil
}
```

or from the beginning cast `arry` as `[[String:Any]]`

Comment: getting error like this :  Use of unresolved identifier 'set'

Comment: declared **var set = Set<String>()**